# How do I efficiently test mediation by Admob/Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I need to test each ad network that Admob/Firebase is mediating in my Android app.

I've configured each ad network to serve test ads for my ids provided to the mediation settings.

To test, I've set one of the networks to the highest eCPM so that Admob/Firebase will prefer it. Then once I verify that network is serving its test ad, I change the eCPM of another network so that that one becomes preferred.

However, it's taking a very long time for the mediation configuration to be pushed to the test device (it's been over 20 minutes now and it's still serving the ad network from the previous configuration). I've tried force-quitting the app and clearing all data from Google Services and the app.

Is there a more efficient way to test each ad network within the Admob/Firebase mediation framework?